# ReplaceAll matched pattern occurance with star. Equal to length of matched string

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, pattern-matching

I needed to write a pattern searcher and replace matched pattern with *, I am able to do that, but the replaced star are of fixed size. I wanted that the replaced stars are of same length as matched pattern. is their any optimized way of doing that.

As in eg-

> you to be replaced by ***
>
> data by ****
>
> and
>
> Us by **

```
         final String REGEX = "data|you|Us";
         final String MASK = "****";
         final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
         String message = "Hai man how are you ? Give me data which you have fetched as it is very important data to Us";
         Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(message);        
         if (matcher.find()) {           
             String maskedMessage = matcher.replaceAll(MASK);             
             System.out.println(maskedMessage);
         }
```

Gives out put- `Hai man how are **** ? Give me **** which **** have fetched as it is very important **** to ****`

I want - `Hai man how are *** ? Give me **** which *** have fetched as it is very important **** to **`

Comment: Is your mask in fact just `*` char? Or does `****` mean that there is a limitation to masking only the first 4 characters?

Comment: Yes my MASK should  * chars. equal to length of of matched pattern

Comment: No there is no limitation of first 4 character.I want to replace whole matched pattern with stars

Comment: Does it mean your `MASK` is actually `*`, or is it user defined? Also, have a look at http://ideone.com/d3T1x7. Does it work as expected?

Comment: No it is * (fixed), Mask is not used, it is fixed. I want to hide pattern in string with *

Comment: Yes it does what need to be done

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following approach: match what you need and use [`Matcher#appendReplacement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement(java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String)) to modify the matched substrings (to replace all chars in it with `*` that you say is a fixed masking char).

```
final String REGEX = "data|you|Us";
final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
String message = "Hai man how are you ? Give me data which you have fetched as it is very important data to Us";
Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(message);        
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();           // Buffer for the result
while (matcher.find()) {                            // Look for partial matches
    String replacement = 
        matcher.group(0).replaceAll(".", "*");      // Replace any char with `*`
    matcher.appendReplacement(result, replacement); // Append the modified string
}
matcher.appendTail(result); // Add the remaining string to the result
System.out.println(result.toString()); // Output the result
```

See the [online Java demo](http://ideone.com/FtFvSg).

NOTE: If your string contains linebreaks, the `replaceAll` inside the `while` block must be changed to `.replaceAll("(?s).", "*")` to also replace linebreak chars with `*`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following codes are easy to be understood.

```
final String REGEX = "data|you|Us";
final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
String message = "Hai man how are you ? Give me data which you have fetched as it is very important data to Us";
Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(message);  
String maskedMessage ="";
while (matcher.find()) { 
   String rs = matcher.group();
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   for(int i = 0 ; i < rs.length(); i++){
       sb.append("*");
   }
   message = message.replace(rs, sb.toString());
   matcher = PATTERN.matcher(message);
}
maskedMessage = message;
System.out.println(maskedMessage);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve it in this way:

```
     final String REGEX = "data|you|Us";
     final String MASK = "*";
     final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
     String message = "Hai man how are you ? Give me data which you have fetched as it is very important data to Us";
     StringBuilder messageBuilder = new StringBuilder(message);
     Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(message);   

     int start=0;
     while (matcher.find(start)) {
         messageBuilder.replace(matcher.start(), matcher.end(), new String(new char[matcher.end()-matcher.start()]).replace("\0", MASK));
         start = matcher.end();
     }

     System.out.println(messageBuilder.toString());
```

Hope this helps.